# Laravel Nova fails to render login page on the live server

Tags: php, laravel

I successfully installed Laravel and Laravel Nova in live server but when I tried to view Nova login page, I get index of/nova page and the page does not redirect any css.

Below is the screenshot of the page rendering:

[image: Laravel Nova login page fails to render correctly in live server]

In the config/nova.php the path is correctly set to:

```
config/nova.php
```

I need help to get this page to display correctly.

Comment: Did you publish nova and registered the routes?

Comment: I published but index of/nova stands still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what the problem was. I got index of/nova because Laravel Nova login page was looking for the css folder, js folder, .htaccess, web.config from the root directory and it could not find then it displays index of/nova.

When I moved css folder, js folder, .htaccess, web.config to the root directory, then voila I get the login exactly as I wanted.

Below is the correct display of laravel login page:

[image]

Thanks everyone who tried their best to help.

Comment: Don't do that! Now your files are unsafe. Anyone can access files like ".env", "logs", "cached files" ... from the url. This is a **high** security issue. You need to configure your .conf or the project path in your hosting panel on **/your-project/public** instead of **/your-project**

Comment: OK. Thanks so much. I will configure the project path and conf file.

Answer (score 2):

In your case the problem might not be with the web application but with the settings of the webserver.

I use Apache and this is what my 'virtual hosts' (`httpd-vhosts.conf`) configuration looks like for one web application:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName laraveltest1
    DocumentRoot "c:/users/jorisj1/source/repos/laraveltest1/public"
    <Directory  "c:/users/jorisj1/source/repos/laraveltest1/public">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In your case the `DocumentRoot` might point to the actual root of the application. Try changing it to the `public` directory.